preposition use
In a recent post I mistakenly said:

Es sota, caballo y rey de preparar ese plato

Why grammatically is this wrong?
I was corrected with

Preparar ese plato es sota, caballo y rey. Cortar, cocer y sazonar y
listo.

Although I now realize this sounds great to my ear, I feel I would continue making the same mistakes with different examples.
How can I learn from this? I specially refer to the preposition use or rather elimination of it. Can anyone explain or give me some more examples to help me get my head around it?
I don't know how to research this type of grammar myself as it is a specific type of sentence.
Here is the link to my previous post.

Let's analyze the second sentence. It's correct.:

Preparar ese plato es sota, caballo y rey.


Subject (S): "Preparar ese plato"

"Preparar" is the verb, acting as the main action.
"Ese plato" is the direct object, specifying what is being prepared.


Predicate (P): "Es sota, caballo y rey"

"Es" is the copular verb (a form of the verb "to be"), indicating a state of being.
"sota, caballo y rey" is an attribute of the verb "ser", serving as the complement of the subject. It's an idiomatic expression describing the how's the dish ("ese plato").



Let's analyze what you said. I agree that's incorrect, but I'll explain you why:

Es sota, caballo y rey de preparar ese plato


Subject (S): "De preparar ese plato"
Predicate (P): "Es sota, caballo y rey"

The subject is the same "De preparar ese plato". But in this case, it contains a preposition "De" that does not make any sense. "De" is a preposition mostly used to "Denote possession or ownership" (see RAE) .
The sentence's subject, "preparar ese plato", does not have an owner. It does not need a "De" because it's a subject, not a complement.
Be conscient that the order of your sentence was not wrong, although S+P is the most used order. It's corrent when saying:
"sota caballo y rey es preparar ese plato".
"De" is a preposition used to introduce complements.
Here you have some correct examples when using "de":

La receta es de mi abuela [S+P]


De mi abuela es la receta [P+S]


Cocinar es de cocineros [S+P]


De cocineros es cocinar [P+S]

